# PHP SOAP client: Cannot set price book to an order

Tags: pricebook, order

I'm PHP Client library to push data to Salesforce (https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP)

I'm trying to create a new order, as I understand, I will need to:

- Create an Order
- Create OrderItems for that Order

When I tried to create a first OrderItem for the Order, it said that I need to assign a price book for the order I created (what I did before but no succeed).

The error message returned from the server: "Order: bad field names on insert/update call: Pricebook2Id"

Any help would be appreciated!

Code to create a new order:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->AccountId = $accountModel->getSfAccountId();
$data->Pricebook2Id = $standardPricebookId;
// Billing
$data->BillingCity = $billingAddress->getCity();
$data->BillingCountry = $billingAddress->getCountry();
$data->BillingPostalCode = $billingAddress->getPostcode();
$data->BillingState = $billingAddress->getRegion();
$data->BillingStreet = $billingAddress->getStreet();
// Shipping
$data->ShippingCity = $shippingAddress->getCity();
$data->ShippingCountry = $shippingAddress->getCountry();
$data->ShippingPostalCode = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
$data->ShippingState = $shippingAddress->getRegion();
$data->ShippingStreet = implode("\n", $shippingAddress->getStreet());

$data->EffectiveDate = $order->getCreatedAt();
$data->Status = 'Draft';

$response = $this->salesForceConnection->create(array($data), 'Order');
```

Code to create a new OrderItem

```
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->PricebookEntryId = $pricebookEntryId;
    $data->Quantity = $item->getQty();
    $data->UnitPrice = $item->getPrice();
    $data->Description = $description;
    $data->OrderId = $sfOrderId;

    $this->salesForceConnection->create(array($data), 'OrderItem');
```

Comment: Hi. Could you post your code please?

Comment: @MartinLezer I updated the post and included code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I know what's going on.

After logging in with `SforceEnterpriseClient`, the endpoint returned from Force.com server has version 27.0, after replacing 27.0 with 28.0, it worked!

Seems like the PHP Toolkit is already out of date. :(